# Determining MSSQL job status and returning 0 or 1 result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write an MSSQL query and determine if a certain job is running or failed/unknown. 
If it is running I want it to return = 0 I it is in any other status 1 or up.

Can anyone help?

I am trying to select from last_run_outcome

Comment: You mean job on sql agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the following stored procedure and store the result in some temporary table, and then evaluate the result:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobactivity  @job_id
```